# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: using a structure defined in header file

Tags: c++, xcode, oop

I'm using xcode 4.2 to build this simple program. I realize there are a lot of post on this error but I haven't found any that answer my problem.
  I am getting an error that I do not understand.
  Here is the compilation output:

> Ld /Users/kotoko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/stw-gyleohvghcrywgcqkihhkkkqeqnl/Build/Products/Debug/stw normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/kotoko/projectos/somethingToWear/stw_v6_xcode/stw
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>       /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -
>
> L/Users/kotoko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/stw-gyleohvghcrywgcqkihhkkkqeqnl/Build/Products/Debug
>   -F/Users/kotoko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/stw-gyleohvghcrywgcqkihhkkkqeqnl/Build/Products/Debug
>   -filelist /Users/kotoko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/stw-gyleohvghcrywgcqkihhkkkqeqnl/Build/Intermediates/stw.build/Debug/stw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/stw.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -o /Users/kotoko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/stw-gyleohvghcrywgcqkihhkkkqeqnl/Build/Products/Debug/stw
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "ClosetItem::lc",
>   referenced from:
>         ClosetItem::ClosetItem(int)in ClosetItem.o
>         ClosetItem::ClosetItem(int)in ClosetItem.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is the code (the main file doesn't even call this objects for now):

```
//
//  ClosetItem.h
//  stw
//

#ifndef stw_ClosetItem_h
#define stw_ClosetItem_h

#include <iostream>

class LeakChecker { 
    int count;
public: 
    LeakChecker() : count(0) {}
    void print() { 
        std::cout << count << std::endl;
    } 
    ~LeakChecker() { print(); } 
    void operator++(int) { count++; } 
    void operator--(int) { count--; }
};

class ClosetItem{

public:
    ClosetItem(int identifier);
    virtual ~ClosetItem() {};


protected:
    static LeakChecker lc;
};
#endif
//
//  ClosetItem.cpp
//  stw
//

#include "ClosetItem.h"
#include <iostream>

ClosetItem::ClosetItem(int identifier){
    lc++;
    std::cout<<"ClosetItem #";
    lc.print();
}
```

Can anyone point me out the problem please?

Comment: Stictly, this is a linker rather than a compiler problem by the look of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't initialized your `static` member:

```
class ClosetItem{

public:
    ClosetItem(int identifier);
    virtual ~ClosetItem() {};


protected:
    static LeakChecker lc;  // <-- uninitialized
};
```

You need to initialize it in an implementation file:

```
//ClosetItem.cpp
LeakChecker ClosetItem::lc; // <-- definition
```

Comment: omg, I feel so silly... XD
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a static LeakChecker variable but need to implement it. In your c++ file add:

`LeakChecker ClosetItem::lc;`

Answer (score 1):

You've not actually defined the `lc` static object. You need something like:

```
LeakChecker ClosetItem::lc;
```